# was not able to parse JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

My JSON is like below and I couldn't parse this. not sure how to go from looking at content in foreach...

My restSharp code is

```
var client = new RestClient("https://survey.qualtrics.com//WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?API_SELECT=ControlPanel&Version=2.5&Request=getPanel&User=dgfdhfgh&Token=DfghgfhghjUNUGaefghjP&Format=JSON&LibraryID=UR_5cJwNFX8lwFXFwp&PanelID=ML_b8IoBrawfm3MCd7");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

client.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());

var result = client.Execute<List<RootObject>>(request);

if (result != null && (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) ) // It's probably not necessary to test both
{

    foreach (var j in result.Content)
    {
       XXXXXXX;

}
```

and JSON is as follows

```
[
{"RecipientID":"MLRP_1BNnjFoPFgeajfT","FirstName":"Darfghryl","LastName":"Wright","Email":"heoaxcvdcbk7@gmail.com","ExternalDataReference":null,"Unsubscribed":"0","EmbeddedData":{"Participant ID":"16941","DateTaken":"20160710","TriggerResponseID":"R_VKe0amWmZIXcuZ3","TriggerSurveyID":"SV_eA35TXE0iRlexBX","AllEmailsSchduledForSurvey2":"yes"}},
{"RecipientID":"MLRP_cCjJTFP6MxpZFhH","FirstName":"fghfgh","LastName":"Henzell","Email":"fghfgh@gmail.com","ExternalDataReference":null,"Unsubscribed":"0","EmbeddedData":{"Participant ID":"29377","DateTaken":"20160711","TriggerResponseID":"R_z14mwG7l7DBCYg1","TriggerSurveyID":"SV_eA35TXE0iRlexBX","AllEmailsSchduledForSurvey2":"yes"}}]
```

and my classes are as below please help

```
public class EmbeddedData
{
    public string Participant_ID { get; set; }
    public string DateTaken { get; set; }
    public string TriggerResponseID { get; set; }
    public string TriggerSurveyID { get; set; }
    public string AllEmailsSchduledForSurvey2 { get; set; }
    public string AllEmailsSchduledForSurvey3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string RecipientID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public object ExternalDataReference { get; set; }
    public string Unsubscribed { get; set; }
    public List<EmbeddedData> EmbeddedData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As per your class definition, it should be Participant_ID in JSON as well whereas there is a space in the name "Participant ID"

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code in future, and provide a [mcve] - we don't need all those properties in order to find the problem, and I suspect that in reducing your actual code/data to a [mcve] you may well have found the issue yourself.

Comment: Yes that's true, but before I go there it doesn't let me access the data from result.content .. not sure how to iterate through the jSON I get from result.content. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
 if (result != null && (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) ) 
 {
   // here I made changes 

    RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();

    List<RootObject> content = deserial.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(result);

    foreach (var cont in content)
    {
        // Do your Stuff
    }


 }
```

Comment: Hi  Muhammad Usman, even though I used the data contract attributes around it, participant ID is still coming up as null. any advice?